# Defining a specific registry for a specific package in .npmrc file

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, .npmrc

I've just come up against something I haven't encountered before.

I have the following need whereby I have private node packages published to both a private and public repository under the same `@scope`. The packages I have published to npmjs.org are public, stable and ready.

The packages we publish to npm.pkg.github.com are private, potentially unstable. not ready for release and/or need to remain private.

So, I was thinking is it possible to do something like this in the .npmrc file:

```
registry=https://registry.npmjs.org/
@scope:registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com
@scope/<SOME_PUBLIC_PACKAGE_NAME>:registry=https://registry.npmjs.org
//npm.pkg.github.com/:_authToken=${NPM_TOKEN}
```

or similar ...

Comment: I'm wondering if I should publish the package to both repository, one for public to use and one for private use which is a mirror ...

Answer (score 1):

Currently, it's not possible. There is an RFC to allow for defining registry per-package instead of per-scope, but it has not been ratified or implemented yet. You can follow this issue for updates https://github.com/npm/statusboard/issues/340. Similar issue raised https://github.com/npm/rfcs/issues/211